# Formatting a Double variable

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a problem with formatting a double variable showing to users. The variable should be a double but after some calculations init, it shows to users including the E sign. How can i remove the E sign from it and only shows it it's normal behavior?

Thanks!

```
double formattedNumber = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#############").format(myNum * calcal));
```

Comment: Why are you performing a calculation, then converting the result to a string, then parsing the string back into a double?

Comment: I've tried to do it directly to have the sum of myNum * calcal but it gave me an error.

Comment: @MohamedHemdan Well, what you tried next is not the solution.

Comment: "it gave me an error" is not a useful description of your symptoms. You may wish to open a fresh StackOverflow question where you show your code to do it directly and explain what problems you encountered.

Comment: Sure CommonsWare. But my question, is there anyway to remove the e sign from the double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to convert double values to a textual representation. The easiest way is to use string formatting. Consider the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.format("%s%n", 1.12345e37);

    System.out.format("%e%n", 1.12345e37);
    System.out.format("%f%n", 1.12345e37);
    System.out.format("%g%n", 1.12345e37);

    System.out.format("%E%n", 1.12345e37);
    System.out.format("%G%n", 1.12345e37);
}
```

When executed it prints the following:

```
1.12345E37
1.123450e+37
11234500000000000000000000000000000000.000000
1.12345e+37
1.123450E+37
1.12345E+37
```

As you can see, the various format patterns give different results. The %f variant gives what I assume is the answer you desire. See [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Dennis...It worked with me but the 6 right digits zeros are appearing in my number. how Can i get remove them?

Comment: You should really read the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) link I put in my answer, as it is all explained in detail there. But, using `%.0f` instead of `%f` gives you no digits after the decimal separator (and also gets rid of the decimal separator).